# How to configure nginx config for strapi and nuxt?

Tags: nginx, nuxt.js, strapi

I need to configure the nginx configuration so that the site `nuxt` is accessible at the usual address, the admin panel `strapi` at the address `/api`.  The site itself works and receives data, but does not receive images from the `uploads` folder from `strapi`.

Also, I can't get into the `strapi` admin panel, since the `strapi` main page is welcome, then there is a redirect to the `/admin` page, which I don't have. I've tried a lot of configuration variations, but I'm not getting it.

What do I need to do?

`/etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf`

```js
upstream strapi {
    server localhost:1337;
}

upstream nuxt {
    server localhost:3000;
}
```

`nuxt.config.ts`

```js
 vite: {
        server: {
            hmr: {
                protocol: "wss",
                clientPort: 443,
                path: "hmr/",
            },
        },
    },
```

`confing`

```js
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 0.0.0.01:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen 0.0.0.01:443 ssl http2;

    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;

    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
}



server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen 0.0.0.01:443 ssl http2;

    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/example.com/client;
    index index.mjs index.html index.xml;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;

    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;



location / {

proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_buffering         on;
        proxy_cache_valid       200 1d;
        proxy_cache_use_stale   error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

        proxy_pass              http://nuxt;
        proxy_read_timeout      1m;
        proxy_connect_timeout   1m;
include proxy_params;

    }

location /api/ {
  rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /$1 break;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
     proxy_pass http://strapi;
        include proxy_params;

}
 location /_nuxt/hmr/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:24678;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read [this](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/admin-panel-customization#different-servers)

Strapi works **only** with subdomain `strapi.exaple.com` or `example.com/strapi`.

Following the guide, you need to create a url that will open the admin panel `strapi`.

I excluded the line `serveAdminPanel: false` from the guide.

String `url: 'http://yourbackend.com` must contain the path to the frontend part of `strapi`

All the addresses of your sites in the `.env` files should have `https` instead of `http`, this is necessary in the frontend part and in the backend part of your application